# Python reference model

Tags: python

I have a hard time to understand the python reference model

```
def changer(a,b):
    a = 2
    b[0] = 'spam'  
X = 1
L = [1,2] 
changer(X,L)  
X,L
(1,['spam',2])
```

here comes my question, for assignment  **b[0] = 'spam'** :  I want to know how python modify the mutable object in this way(instead of create a new string objects and link the variable b to that object which will not affect the original object pointed by L)

thanks

Comment: This will help you understand: http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/

Comment: What exactly is confusing you? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference? Is there something there that is unclear?

Comment: @Apero: That explanation tries to be cute and look simple, but I actually find it kind of confusing (maybe because I'm not German?). This one is much better: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` and `b` are both references to objects.

When you reassign `a` you change which object `a` is referencing.

When you reassign `b[0]` you are reassigning another reference contained *within* `b`. `b` itself still references the same list object that it did originally, which is also the list that was passed into the `changer` function.

Comment: what if I change the assignment to `b = [3,4]` ;  it will still reassign references contained within `b`?  can i make it this way: a variable which points to a mutable object contain several references within it ?

Comment: @SuperZhuoli if you do `b = [3,4]` you are reassigning `b` to a new list object, which contains two additional references to the objects `3` and `4`.

Comment: Ok got it . when i print out `L`; i will get `[1,2]` thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Variables name are pointers to a special memory address ,so when you pass `L` and `X` to function the function does not create a new address with `a,b` just changed the labels !, so any changes on those actually change the value of that part of memory that `X,L` point to. So for refuse that you can use `copy` module :

```
>>> from copy import copy
>>> def changer(a,b):
...     i = copy(a)
...     j = copy(b)
...     i = 2
...     j[0] = 'spam'
... 
>>> X = 1
>>> L = [1,2] 
>>> changer(X,L) 
>>> X,L
(1, [1, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, lists are mutable, and integers are immutable.  This means that Python will never actually change the value of an integer stored in memory, it creates a new integer and points the variable at the new one.

The reason for this is to make Python's dynamic typing work.  Unlike most languages, you can create a variable and store an int in it, then immediately store a string in it, or a float, etc.

```
MyVariable = 10     # This creates an integer and points MyVariable at it.
MyVariable = "hi"   # Created a new string and MyVariable now points to that.
MyVariable = 30     # Created a new integer, and updated the pointer
```

So this is what happens in your code:

```
MyVar = 1   # An integer is created and MyVar points to it.

def Increase(num):
   num = num + 1   #A new integer is created, the temp variable num points at it.

Increase(MyVar)
print(MyVar)    # MyVar still points to the original integer
```

This is a 'feature' of dynamically typed languages ;)